# Setting an variable using jquery .attr and then changing it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of fields and some of them have labels like

```
<input id="1" /><label for="1" />
<input id="2" />
<input id="3" /><label for="3" />
```

For every label i want to do something like

```
var for_label = $(label).attr("for");
```

and then use the variable to apply a style to the appropriate input-field. How should I do this? I would much appreciate an example, I'm pretty new to Javascript...

Comment: IDs should not start with numbers.

Comment: thanks a bunch, it was just a example thoght, the actual html is a lot more complex!

Comment: @felix , i know its not a good practice , but why should we not have numbers as ids.., it is not allowed or its just a convintion.

Comment: @gov, it is not allowed. Look at [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name)

Comment: Kristoffer, I know you have a lot of choices out there when choosing and answer and I would just like to state that I enjoy answering your questions, in particular, and that you're a super guy

Comment: @Gaby - Not allowed in HTML4 specifically. HTML5 allows it.

Comment: Thank's a bunch @hunter! that really warms my heart! It's what this community is all about to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('label').each(function() {
    // Get corresponding input element:
    var input = $('#' + $(this).attr('for'));
    // apply some CSS class 
    input.css('someStyle');
});
```

As a side note ids cannot start with numbers.

Comment: Darin - I think for `<label>` elements, the correct property is `this.htmlFor` since `for` is a reserved word.

Comment: can you do `this.for`? I'm thinking you'd have to write `this[0].for`

Comment: Because the `$()` function returns a jquery object. Use `this.for` to get the id.

Comment: @hunter, no, inside the `each` callback `this` points to the current element that's being enumerated. In this case it points to a label. So you don't have `this[0].id`, nor `this.id`, you should use `this.for` as you want the `for` attribute.

Comment: @Darin - `this.for` will fail in some browsers. See my first comment.

Comment: @Darin - Your correction will work of course, but I'd still do a direct property access. You just can't use `for`, but would need to use `htmlFor` instead. I'm pretty certain that it is widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

`$(label).attr("for")` will return the id of the label, [using the attr method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). You then want to [select the element with that id](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) so: `$("#" + $(label).attr("for"))` now you have the input element selected. You can change it's style with [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/). For example: `$("#" + $(label).attr("for")).css("color", "blue")`.
[To loop through all the labels you can d](http://api.jquery.com/each/)o:

```
$("label").each(function(){
  $("#" + $(this).attr("for")).css("color", "blue");//note that this refers to the label in this context
});
```